# Edit distance string and list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python edit distance, the code I wrote is only comparing two words, but how about if I want to compare a word and a list of words?

Here's my code:

```
def fdistance(S1,S2):
    a = len(S1)
    b = len(S2)
    fdn = {} # Global dict
    for x in range(a+1):
        fdn[x,0] = x
    for y in range(b+1):
        fdn[0,y] = y

    for x in range(1,a+1):
        for y in range(1,b+1):
            if S1[x-1] == S2[y-1]: 
                c = 0 
            else:
                c = 1                 
            fdn[x,y] = min(fdn[x,y-1]+1, fdn[x-1,y]+1, fdn[x-1,y-1]+c)
    return fdn[x,y]
```

But it only can print the distance between string and string. My question is if S2 is a list, so how to compare a string and a list?

Comment: How would you compare a string and a list? What would you expect the output to be if the input is `fdistance('Hello', [1,2,3])`?

Comment: S2 is a list contains strings. For example:fdistance( 'hello', ['halo', 'hallo', 'help'])

Comment: You have the distance for two strings. Write a separate function for comparing a string and a list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function to compare two words.

To compare a word against a list of words:

```
>>> words = ['halo', 'hallo', 'help']
>>> [fdistance('hello', word) for word in words]
[2, 1, 2]
```